# Recieve names and versions of installed MSI packages

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I need to get names and versions of all installed MSI packages on local machine from C# project. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller namespace found in Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  It has:

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductInstallation> GetProducts(
    string productCode,
    string userSid,
    UserContexts context
)
```

> productCode (String)
>
> ProductCode (GUID) of the product instances to be
>   enumerated. Only instances of products within the scope of the context
>   specified by the userSid and context parameters will be enumerated.
>   This parameter may be set to null to enumerate all products in the
>   specified context.
>
> userSid (String)
>
> Specifies a security identifier
>   (SID) that restricts the context of enumeration. A SID value other
>   than s-1-1-0 is considered a user SID and restricts enumeration to the
>   current user or any user in the system. The special SID string s-1-1-0
>   (Everyone) specifies enumeration across all users in the system. This
>   parameter can be set to null to restrict the enumeration scope to the
>   current user. When context is set to the machine context only, userSid
>   must be null.
>
> context (UserContexts)
>
> Specifies the user context.

that wraps the Win32 MSI API MsiEnumProductsEx function.  This brings back a collection of ProductInstallation that you can do Linq queries against to find out anything you need to know about installed MSI's.